# VBA Blank Line In TextBox Causes Error

Tags: vba, excel

When having someone enter an input in a TextBox in VBA in  Word 2016 64bit if they enter a blank line at the end of the textbox the program crashes and throws this error out. I can not figure out how to fix this and do not know what to try.

[image]

**TextBox:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
Set ccs = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("CreditNotes")
Set cc = ccs(1)
cc.Range.Text = CreditNotes.Text'
```

I then get the 5844 error but only if there is a blank line at the end of the textbox. Otherwise it works.

What code should I use to automatically take out the blank line so this will not throw out an error?

Comment: Is there any code associated with generating the textbox?

Comment: Nope. It does not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024402/how-to-remove-line-break-in-string  should help you int he right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try:

```
cc.Range.Text = Replace(CreditNotes.Text, vbCrLf, vbNullString)
```