# Remove blank line in a string

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to remove blank lines in a string as follows:

"First section

Second section

Third section"

I display a rolling index on every content slide so as you click through the slides, the index highlights the section you are in. I don't want to display subsections, so I tried to replace section names starting with "-" with "", but that means I have blank lines. So now I want to remove the blank lines.

I tried:

- IIF statements but replacing with "" doesn't remove a blank line
- Regular expressions, another link suggested the following pattern would work:  @"^\s+$[\r\n]*" but the @ throws up an error and it doesn't work in any case

I tried something like the below:

```vb
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

With RE
    .Multiline = True
    .Global = True  
    resultString = .Replace(subjectString, "\s\n", string.empty)
    MsgBox resultString
End With
```

Another potential solution I found on stackoverflow.

```vb
Dim xArr() as string
xArr = Split(TextBox1.Value, vbCrLf)
TextBox1.Value = ""

for i = 0 to Ubound(xArr)
    If Trim(xArr(i)) <> "" Then
        TextBox1.value = TextBox1.value & xArr(i) & vbCrLf
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024402/how-to-remove-line-break-in-string) might help your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your RegEx code is actually intended for VB.Net rather than VBA, the code below replaces *n* blank lines with 1 in VBA.

```
Dim RE As Object: Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

With RE
    .MultiLine = True
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "(\r\n)+"

    resultString = .Replace(subjectString, vbCrLf)

    MsgBox resultString
End With
```

Of course if you only ever have *2* blank lines you can simply:

```
resultString = replace$(subjectString, vbcrlf & vbcrlf, vbcrlf)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Alex K - really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but here's a regex Public Function i made to help. Theres probably a better way but this was simple for me and worked.

```
'=================================================================================='
Public Function RegExReplace(TextContent As String, SearchEx As String, Optional ReplaceEx As String = "", Optional _
                    EmptyLines As Boolean = False, Optional TrimLines As Boolean = True) As String
    Dim regEx As Object, strOutput As String
    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With regEx: .Global = True: .IgnoreCase = False: .MultiLine = True: .Pattern = SearchEx: End With
    TextContent = regEx.Replace(TextContent, ReplaceEx)
    If EmptyLines = False Then TextContent = RegExReplace(TextContent, "\r\n\r\n", "", True, False)
    If TrimLines = True Then TextContent = Trim(TextContent)
    
    RegExReplace = TextContent: Set regEx = Nothing
End Function
'=================================================================================='
```

Answer (score 1):

If for whatever reason you'd prefer to avoid using RegEx (working on a Mac where VBScript isn't available for example), here's a purely VB approach:

```
Sub Test()
    Call TakeOutTheEmpties(ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1))
End Sub
Sub TakeOutTheEmpties(oSh As Shape)

    Dim oPara As TextRange
    Dim x As Long
    
    If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
        If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
            For x = oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
                Set oPara = oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(x)
                If oPara.Text = vbCr Then
                    oPara.Delete
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```